# Is it possible to configure proxy setting through dhcp?

Tags: proxy, dhcp

I have a small LAN with 12 devices connected to it, ubuntu box running dnsmasq acting as a dhcp server and another ubuntu box acting as a web proxy. 
Is it possible to configure all of the devices in the network through the dhcp server to use this web proxy ?

Comment: [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/bootp-dhcp-parameters/bootp-dhcp-parameters.xhtml#options) has reserved option number 135 for `HTTP Proxy for phone-specific applications`. That's the only mention of proxy I could find in the list of possible options. Unfortunately no RFC is mentioned, so I have no idea how that option is supposed to work.

Comment: You could configure a transparent proxy instead.

Comment: If you mean to force the computers/applications to use your proxy, then, no.

Answer (score 12):

You can configure your DHCP server for **[Web Proxy Autodiscovery Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Autodiscovery_Protocol)**:

Create a [PAC file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) and host it on a local web server. Then have your DHCP server provide the URL of the PAC file (e.g. `http://mywebserver/proxy.pac`) in DHCP option 252:

```
option auto-proxy-config code 252 = " http://mywebserver/proxy.pac";
```

Comment: That leading space is a typo right?